# SQL Server stored procedure with multiple row result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This might be a really silly question - when executing the following stored procedure, is the result a table-value result? I've learned that stored procedure can't deal with 2D result (please correct me if I am wrong!), then what about this example? And can I call this result as output? What is the difference between results and output? Thanks in advance!

```
create proc sp_emp_data 
as 
    select jobtitle, gender
    from adventureworks2012.humanresources.employee

exec sp_emp_data
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: What do you mean by *2D result* ? A stored procedure can return a result set of rows and columns - several of those, in fact. Is that what you mean? Multiple result sets? Or do you mean you cannot even return a single row/column result set ?? That wouldn't be very useful at all !!